# What does an AC signal look like when it is grounded with a DC signal?

Tags: ac, dc, rectifier

Sorry if something doesn't make sense, I am not an electronic engineer, if I need to clarify something, please tell me to :)

I am upgrading the light on my motorcycle to an LED light.

My problem is that the power for the light comes directly from the generator unrectified (I think.) This makes the light flicker at low RPM.

In the manual, I can see that the black wire from the light socket (ground) goes to the same wire as the negative terminal of the DC circuit.

Does anyone know if the signal at the headlight will be AC, going between a negative voltage and a positive voltage, or an alternating DC signal, since the ground wire goes to the ground in a DC circuit?

I need to know this because if the signal is a DC signal, I won't need to rectify it first, and since my full-bridge rectifiers have a high voltage drop, it would be nice if I could exclude them. :)

I have tried to draw on the wiring diagram, where the light is connected to both the AC side and the DC side.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It does look like the headlight runs on AC - this is quite common, since filament lamps work well on AC and it avoids having a rectifier in that part of the circuit.  So for a LED replacement you will need a rectifier.  This won’t resolve the flicker at low revs though, adding a capacitor may help.

Comment: Thank you :) Yes, i am in the process of designing a rectifier with capacitors. I was just confused, as I did not know if an AC signal could occur when it goes to the ground of a DC circuit.

Comment: It's not uncommon for AC and DC to share the same ground. To figure out if the current is AC or DC, you have to look at the whole current loop from source, through your device, back to your source. It's a little confusing since the path goes through some fuse boxes,  but the current does come from the alternator (not the DC battery). The reason why AC and DC share the same ground is for safety reasons. You don't want some parts of the bike's chassis charged up differently relative to other parts (shock hazzard), so you make them all the same voltage.

Comment: If using 12W of Hi Bright or 1A the cap would need to be too big to be useful

Comment: @KD9PDP is correct, the frame is invariably used as ground, as this avoids having to run ground wires.  Getting a really smooth DC output would require a very large capacitor, but anything is better than nothing.  Depending on the LED it may operate down to quite a low voltage, so a capacitor could help.  I'd estimate that 47000uF at 25V would be enough to make a difference.

Comment: My LED headlight draws around 2 - 3A. Currently, I have 10000uF capacitors on it, and it seems to do pretty well, but does not get rid of all flicker.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be half-wave rectified AC voltage so lots of flicker with LEDs at 600 RPM or 10 or ? 20 Hz

Since LEDs will be more efficient, you can measure lamp voltage then choose to rewire lamps to DC if you consider all the other lamps and current load on the rectifier.

[image]

Comment: So what you are suggesting is that the headlight should only have a positive voltage? I thought about just adding another bridge rectifier to take care of entire the light circuit.